# How can I add the used base (FROM) image to a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

As far as I know it is not possible to get the value of the FROM instruction from a built image, I can get the sha256 of the used based image, because its one of the layers in the built image, but I can't get the tag, which was used in the Dockerfile.

So I want to add the information of the instruction FROM to the built image.

The only solution that came to my mind is to add the information as label:

`FROM docker.private.org/base:latest
LABEL dockerfile.baseimage=docker.private.org/base:latest`

But this means that I have to duplicate the base image tag information.
Does anybody know how I could solve this requirement, without duplication of the base image tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can label a container during starting it / docker-compose

```
docker run -l dockerfile.baseimage=docker.private.org/base:latest docker.private.org/base:latest
```

You can also use labels in docker-compose.yml https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/labels

Sure, that is a copy of the information and can get out of sync, but you either go the way bundling this information in the image, thus creating your own image, or you add this using labels during runtime. I do not think there is a other way